# How can I edit strings in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am importing a dataset from SAS which has columns with named headers, and thousands of rows of entries, which I have named `start_list`. one column is **fund**, in which we have a selection of strings eg '**South East Auth**', '**North West**', '**South**' etc. I want to add the word 'auth' to the North west and South strings, but leave the strings that already have this sunch as south east, alone.
I don't need to do anything clever like look for auth - there are only a few that need changing. I just want to basically, in laymans code, do
`if string in column 'fund' = 'south east' then change to 'south east auth'` and apply this to thousands of instances of it

Comment: You may do `i1 <- df1$fund %in% c("North West", "South"); df1$fund[i1] <- paste(df1$fund[i1], "Auth")`  or more dynamically `i1 <- grep("Auth$", df1$fund, negate = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE); df1$fund[i1] <- paste(df1$fund[i1], "Auth")`

Answer (score 1):

```r
vec <- c("South West", "South East", "North East", "North West")
paste0(vec, ifelse(vec %in% c("South East", "North West"), " Auth", "")) 
# [1] "South West"      "South East Auth" "North East"      "North West Auth"
```

If you want it to be case-insensitive,

```r
paste0(vec, ifelse(tolower(vec) %in% c("south east", "north west"), " Auth", ""))
# [1] "South West"      "South East Auth" "North East"      "North West Auth"
```